# How to config Multiple virtual sound card in CentOS 5.6?

Tags: linux, centos, alsa

I use cmds :

```
/sbin/modprobe snd-dummy
aplay -l
```

Only one  virtual sound card show :

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Dummy [Dummy], device 0: Dummy PCM [Dummy PCM]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
```

Is there any way to setup 2~4 virtual sound card ?

Comment: To do what exactly afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

OK,I found the way:

```
/sbin/modprobe snd-dummy pcm_devs=4
```

It will add 4 devs